# Why am I unable to access form data when submitting using OnChange?

Tags: php, forms, mysqli, submit, onchange

I have a simple HTML select option in which it should automatically send `OnChange`. The form seems to send or "Reload the page" should I say. I am not getting ANY data the other end. I have tried `POST` and `GET` I have renamed every section of the forms data and changed the entire `if(isset()` information. Any ideas why I am not getting any data?

FORM:

```
<?php
$system1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conn, 
               "SELECT * FROM ap_system_status WHERE system_id = '1'"));
$system_id_1 = $system1['system_id'];
$system_name_1 = $system1['system_name'];
$system_status_1 = $system1['system_status'];
?>
<strong><? echo $system_name_1; ?></strong> 
<div align="right" style="float:right">
    <div class="form-group">
        <form action="" method="GET" id="system_status" name="system_status">
            <input type="hidden" id="system_id" value="<? echo $system_id_1; ?>" />
            <select class="form-control" onchange="this.form.submit()" id="status">
                <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" hidden="hidden"><? echo $system_status_1; ?></option>
                <option value='<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" style="color:#F60"></i> Experiencing Errors'>Experiencing Errors</option>
                <option value='<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" style="color:#F60"></i> Being Updated'>Being Updated</option>
                <option value='<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" style="color:#F60"></i> Maintenance Mode'>Maintenance Mode</option>
                <option value='<i class="fa fa-times-circle-o" style="color:#F00"></i> System Offline'>System Offline</option>
                <option value='<i class="fa fa-check-circle-o" style="color:#090"></i> Good Service'>Good Service</option>
            </select> 
            <noscript><input type="submit" value="Submit"></noscript>
       </form>
```

DATA COLLECTION (Very basic but only testing!!):

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['system_status'])){
    $system_id = $_POST['system_id'];
    $status = $_POST['status'];
    echo $system_id;
    echo $status;
}else{

}
?>
```

Comment: Your select does not have a `name`.

Comment: I've added a name and changed to `post` and still nothing

Comment: You check `if(isset($_POST['system_status'])){`, but I don't see where that would be set. Naming the form that will not have that effect.

Comment: When I remove the "onChange" and use the submit button, the form processes correctly.

Comment: If the submit button was named 'system_status', that would be why it worked. You should be able to remove that isset check if the button is no longer there.

Comment: Removing the isset check worked! Thanks very much, if you post, I will accept as correct! thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of changes to your form and PHP should get this working. In order for the form elements to be submitted with the form, they must have `name` attributes, and the form `method` must match the superglobal (`$_GET` or `$_POST`) you are accessing in PHP.

```
<!--Change the form method to match what you are using in your PHP-->
<form action="" method="POST" id="system_status" name="system_status">
    <!--Add a name to this input-->
    <input type="hidden" id="system_id" value="<? echo $system_id_1; ?>" name="system_id" />
    <!--Add a name to this select-->
    <select class="form-control" onchange="this.form.submit()" id="status" name="status">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" hidden="hidden"><? echo $system_status_1; ?></option>
        <!--Not related to your question, but switch the value attribute with the
        option text so you can see your icons and get the value I assume you expect-->
        <option value="Experiencing Errors"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" style="color:#F60"></i> Experiencing Errors</option>
        ...
    </select>
    <noscript><input type="submit" value="Submit"></noscript>
```

I would actually not recommend getting rid of the `isset` check altogether, but modifying it so that it actually verifies that the values you are going to use are present.

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['system_id']) && !empty($_POST['status'])) {
    $system_id = $_POST['system_id'];
    $status = $_POST['status'];
    echo $system_id;
    echo $status;
} else {
    // error handling for missing values
}
```